# How to Include a 'No Shift' Scenario in a Temperature Shift DOE

Tags: experiment-design, factor-analysis, jmp

I'm currently working on a Design of Experiments (DOE) for a process that involves temperature shifts at three different times. My challenge is incorporating a 'No Shift' scenario as one of the factors.

My initial idea was to:

1. Treat the three time points for temperature shifts (1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours) as a continuous factor.
2. Introduce a 'No Shift' scenario as a categorical factor (yes/no).

However, I'm struggling with how to implement this without creating illogical combinations of 'No Shift' with a time point.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to set up a mixed-level factor that combines continuous and categorical levels without creating invalid combinations?
- Are there alternative approaches that would be recommended here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: could you clarify the characteristics of your data? It sounds like you have three continuous variables (i.e., time 1, time 2, and time 3) and one categorical variable (no shift) is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And that is exactly the issue, as I am using two different factors to look at just one thing. But I am puzzled on how to do this any differently.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set up a mixed-level factor that combines continuous and categorical levels without creating invalid combinations?

Yes, it is possible to fit a [factor analysis (FA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) model with mixed data$^1$. See the code below, which fits a [confirmatory factor analysis (CFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmatory_factor_analysis) to a simulated data set similar to yours (i.e., three continuous variables, and one dichotomous variable) using the `R` package `lavaan`. I am not sure if `jmp` can or not, though I would think so.

```
# Packages
library(lavaan)
library(tidyverse)

# Model specification for simulation
model_sim <- '
  # Latent variable definition
  F1 =~ 0.7*hour1 + 0.7*hour2 + 0.7*hour3 + 0.7*noshift
'


# Simulate the data
set.seed(123)
simData <- simulateData(model = model_sim, sample.nobs = 1000) %>% 
 mutate(noshift = ifelse(noshift < 0, 0,1))

# Model specification for fitting the model
model <- '
  # Latent variable definition
  F1 =~ hour1 + hour2 + hour3 + noshift
'
# Fit the model to the simulated data
fit <- cfa(model, data = simData, ordered = c("noshift"), std.lv = TRUE)

# Output the summary of the fit
summary(fit)
```

> Are there alternative approaches that would be recommended here?

I am sure there are. Though I would need additional information about your problem.

$^1$ Specifically, this is done using the [biserial correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) which is used when one item is dichotomous and the other is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me provide a better context. In my DoE, I'm examining the effect of a temp. shift from 37°C to 35°C on antibody production using mammalian cells. The shift can occur 1 h, 2 h, or 3 h into the process. However, I also want to include a scenario where this shift does not happen. The purpose is to maximize the yield of the antibody, which is measured only once at the very end of the process. So far, I have designed this using a categorical factor indicating whether the shift occurs (Yes/No) and a continuous factor specifying the shift's time (1h, 2h, 3h).

Comment: But if the combinations are:

| Temperature shift (yes/no) | Temperature shift time (h) |
| -------- | -------------- |
| yes | 1 |
| yes | 2 |
| yes | 3 |
| no | 1 |
| no | 2 |
| no | 3 |

Treatments 4, 5, and 6 are essentially triplicates of the same "no shift". Isn't this wasteful in terms of treatment allocation? How do I then interpret the main effects and interactions? Is there a better way to do this?